# unable to insert date in sql table

Tags: sql-server

using python pyodbc I am trying to insert date and time in a table but getting

"
('22007', u'[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')
"

Insert query:

```
 cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO DM (SI, DK, Total, CR, CCM, SDate, EDate)
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, convert(datetime, ?, 121))""",dms)
```

tried following formats to insert date and time:

```
20190201 01:14:54.862963
20190201T01:14:54.862963
```

Please note while inserting with date alone that is 20190201 I was able to insert but only with date and time facing the issue
Tired following query too. with this query able to insert date

```
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO DM (SI, DK, Total, CR, CCM, SDate, EDate)
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)""",dms)
```

Comment: It's a `datetime` column? What version of SQL Server? Did you try with only three decimal places, e.g. `20190201 01:14:54.862`...

Comment: I am pretty sure that you need separator characters in the date '2019-02-01T01:14:54.862' to be in ISO date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These formats are not valid and cannot be automatically converted to datetime.

20190201 01:14:54.862963

20190201T01:14:54.862963

You can insert the following format :

```
insert into test values (1,2,convert(datetime,'20190201 01:14:54.862',121))
```

Otherwise, if your data is in the presented format, you can perform the following workaround, by removing the last 3 digits.

```
insert into test values (1,2,convert(datetime,substring('20190201 01:14:54.862963',1,len('20190201 01:14:54.862963')-3),121))
```

Hope this will help you.